# .htaccess rewrite not working in tandem with Alias from virtual host

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following file setup

```
/var/www
  |-app1
      - index.php
      - .htaccess
  |-app2
      - index.php
      - .htaccess
```

In virtual hosts I have an alias setup because I want to serve different apps according to url:

```
Alias /application1 /var/www/app1
Alias /application2 /var/www/app2
```

All works well: if I access `/aplication1` but if I access `/application1/something/` I get 404 but this shouldn't happen because of `.htaccess` from each app folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you ever though about what the `RewriteBase` directive actually does? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase

Comment: I have added `RewriteBase /app1/` and I still get 404 for `application1/something/`

Comment: Solved it by using `RewriteBase /application1/`. I was confused thinking that it's referring to folder not url.

Comment: That value is used to make an absolute path form the relative path rewritten to. That is required since a URLneeds to have an absolute path, not a relative one. So indeed that setting influences the rewritten URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to add alias to RewriteBase in `.htaccess`. Ex:

```
RewriteBase /application1/
```